# postman not working while performing get and post method in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, backend

[postman stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPaLD.png)please check the code if any mistake i did because in postman while sending the post request ,im not getting any response , it is only showing sending request .
Mongodb also connected .

this is my index.js code , please help me out of this

```
process.env.TZ = 'Asia/Calcutta';
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
var cCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
const cluster = require('cluster');
const express = require('express');
const reader = require('xlsx');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const multer = require('multer');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const db = require('./Config/Keys').mongoURI;
const logger = require('./Config/workerlog');
const myrecord = require('./model/myrecord');

mongoose
  .connect(db, {
    keepAlive: true,
  })
  .then(() => logger.info('MongoDB Connected'))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    var datetimestamp = Date.now();
    cb(
      null,
      file.fieldname +
        '-' +
        datetimestamp +
        '.' +
        file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length - 1]
    );
  },
});
var uploads = multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: function (req, file, callback) {
    //file filter

    if (
      ['xls', 'xlsx', 'csv'].indexOf(
        file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length - 1]
      ) === -1
    ) {
      return callback(new Error('Wrong extension type'));
    }
    callback(null, true);
  },
}).single('file');

app.post('/Getexcelfile', async function (req, res) {
  uploads(req, res, async function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(404).json({ Message: 'Something went to wrong...!' });
    }
    if (!req.file) {
      return res.status(404).json({ Message: 'Please Choose file' });
    }
    try {
      const file = reader.readFile(`${req.file.path}`);

      var data = [];
      try {
        var sheets = file.SheetNames;
        for (let i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
          const temp = reader.utils.sheet_to_json(
            file.Sheets[file.SheetNames[i]]
          );
          temp.forEach((res) => {
            data.push(res);
          });
        }
      } catch (e) {}
      await record.insertMany(req.body.BulkData).then((res) => {
        res.json({
          path: req.file.path,
          test: data,
        });
        res.json(ress);
      });
    } catch (e) {}
  });
});

app.get('/GetRecordDetails', async (req, res) => {
  myrecord.find().then((ResponseData) => {
    res.json(ResponseData);
  });
});

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // Create a worker for each CPU
  for (var i = 0; i < cCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }
} else {
  app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port  ${port}`));
}
```

want to perform get and post in postman . please check the code and help me to solve the problems

Comment: You've got a bunch of `catch` blocks with nothing in them. At the very least you could try `console.error(e); return res.status(500).send(e);`

Comment: If you're immediately reading the file into memory, you might as well use Multer's InMemory storage